# Find the fifth working day between 2 dates sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am trying to find the fifth working day between two dates, excluding also holidays.

This is the query I wrote:

```
with s_date as (select TO_DATE('21-04-2020','DD-MM-YYYY') d from dual),
     e_date as (select TO_DATE('01-05-2020','DD-MM-YYYY') d from dual),
     no_of_days as (select abs(trunc(s_date.d -  e_date.d))+1 no from s_date,e_date),
    cal as (select d+rownum-1 dt
            from s_date
            connect by level <= (select no from no_of_days) )
select cal.dt  from cal where to_char(cal.dt, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
and cal.dt not in (select day from T_PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS) order by cal.dt desc;
```

Output:

```
DT
1:30-04-2020
2:29-04-2020
3:28-04-2020
4:27-04-2020
5:24-04-2020
6:23-04-2020
7:22-04-2020
8:21-04-2020
```

How can I limit the output to only :
DT
1:
24-04-2020

Answer (score 0):

Put it to another SELECT statement and use ROWNUM.

```
select date_value FROM (
select cal.dt as date_value, ROWNUM as row_num from cal where to_char(cal.dt, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
and cal.dt not in (select day from T_PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS) order by cal.dt desc
)) WHERE row_num = 5
```

Btw your whole SQL statement is ugly and you should not use that :)

Comment: Ugly but working on so many release of Oracle. Mine applies on recent ones.

Answer (score 0):

First create additional column to order the day in your result and select any day you want, in your case day_order = 6

```
select 
    cal.dt 
    , rank() over (order by cal.dt) as day_order    
from cal 
where to_char(cal.dt, 'dy', 'nls_date_language=english') not in ('sat', 'sun') 
and cal.dt not in (select day from T_PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS)
```

the code would like:

```
with 
s_date as
(
select to_date('21-04-2020','dd-mm-yyyy') d from dual
)
, e_date as 
(
select to_date('01-05-2020','dd-mm-yyyy') d from dual
)
, no_of_days as 
(
select abs(trunc(s_date.d -  e_date.d))+1 no from s_date,e_date
)
, cal as
(   
select d+rownum-1 dt
from s_date
connect by level <= (select no from no_of_days) 
)
, cal2 as 
(select 
    cal.dt 
    , rank() over (order by cal.dt) as day_order    
from cal 
where to_char(cal.dt, 'dy', 'nls_date_language=english') not in ('sat', 'sun') 
and cal.dt not in (select day from T_PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS)
)
select dt from cal2 
where day_order = 5 -- day_order = 6 if you want to exclude the start day
```

Answer (score 0):

This will calculate the values for multiple start dates and offset dates in one statement:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( start_date, days ) AS
SELECT DATE '2019-01-01' + date_offset, days
FROM   ( SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS date_offset FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7 )
       CROSS JOIN
       ( SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS days FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7 );

CREATE TABLE holidays ( holiday_date ) AS
SELECT DATE '2019-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2019-01-09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2019-01-10' FROM DUAL;
```

Create a helper function to add weekdays. This is not necessary as you can unroll the function into the query but it makes it much more obvious what is occurring:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION add_weekdays(
  start_date IN DATE,
  weekdays   IN NUMBER
) RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN start_date
         -- add full weeks
         + FLOOR( weekdays / 5 ) * 7
         -- check to see if the remaining days go over a weekend, if so add 2 extra days
         + CASE WHEN ( start_date - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ) ) + MOD( weekdays, 5 ) >= 5
           THEN MOD( weekdays, 5 ) + 2
           ELSE MOD( weekdays, 5 )
           END;
END;
/
```

**Query**:

```sql
WITH offsets ( start_date, days, offset_date, holiday_days ) AS (
  SELECT start_date,
         days,
         add_weekdays( start_date, days ),
         ( SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM   holidays
           WHERE  holiday_date BETWEEN start_date
                               AND add_weekdays( start_date, days )
         )
  FROM   test_data
UNION ALL
  -- recurse and add the previously found holiday days and look to see if any more holidays overlap
  SELECT start_date,
         days,
         add_weekdays( offset_date, holiday_days ),
         ( SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM   holidays
           WHERE  holiday_date BETWEEN offset_date + 1
                               AND add_weekdays( offset_date, holiday_days )
         )
  FROM   offsets
  -- stop recursing when no holiday days are found
  WHERE  holiday_days > 0
)
CYCLE start_date, days, offset_date SET is_cycle TO 1 DEFAULT 0
SELECT TO_CHAR( start_date, 'DY YYYY-MM-DD' ) AS start_dt,
       days,
       TO_CHAR( offset_date, 'DY YYYY-MM-DD' ) AS offset_dt,
       ( offset_date - start_date ) - days AS skipped_days
FROM   offsets
WHERE  holiday_days = 0
ORDER BY start_date, days;
```

**Output**:

(Holiday dates for testing are `2019-01-01`, `2019-01-09` and `2019-01-10` and the count of skipped days includes holiday days and weekends)

> ```
> START_DT       | DAYS | OFFSET_DT      | SKIPPED_DAYS
> :------------- | ---: | :------------- | -----------:
> TUE 2019-01-01 |    0 | WED 2019-01-02 |            1
> TUE 2019-01-01 |    1 | THU 2019-01-03 |            1
> TUE 2019-01-01 |    2 | FRI 2019-01-04 |            1
> TUE 2019-01-01 |    3 | MON 2019-01-07 |            3
> TUE 2019-01-01 |    4 | TUE 2019-01-08 |            3
> TUE 2019-01-01 |    5 | FRI 2019-01-11 |            5
> TUE 2019-01-01 |    6 | MON 2019-01-14 |            7
> WED 2019-01-02 |    0 | WED 2019-01-02 |            0
> WED 2019-01-02 |    1 | THU 2019-01-03 |            0
> WED 2019-01-02 |    2 | FRI 2019-01-04 |            0
> WED 2019-01-02 |    3 | MON 2019-01-07 |            2
> WED 2019-01-02 |    4 | TUE 2019-01-08 |            2
> WED 2019-01-02 |    5 | FRI 2019-01-11 |            4
> WED 2019-01-02 |    6 | MON 2019-01-14 |            6
> THU 2019-01-03 |    0 | THU 2019-01-03 |            0
> THU 2019-01-03 |    1 | FRI 2019-01-04 |            0
> THU 2019-01-03 |    2 | MON 2019-01-07 |            2
> THU 2019-01-03 |    3 | TUE 2019-01-08 |            2
> THU 2019-01-03 |    4 | FRI 2019-01-11 |            4
> THU 2019-01-03 |    5 | MON 2019-01-14 |            6
> THU 2019-01-03 |    6 | TUE 2019-01-15 |            6
> FRI 2019-01-04 |    0 | FRI 2019-01-04 |            0
> FRI 2019-01-04 |    1 | MON 2019-01-07 |            2
> FRI 2019-01-04 |    2 | TUE 2019-01-08 |            2
> FRI 2019-01-04 |    3 | FRI 2019-01-11 |            4
> FRI 2019-01-04 |    4 | MON 2019-01-14 |            6
> FRI 2019-01-04 |    5 | TUE 2019-01-15 |            6
> FRI 2019-01-04 |    6 | WED 2019-01-16 |            6
> SAT 2019-01-05 |    0 | MON 2019-01-07 |            2
> SAT 2019-01-05 |    1 | TUE 2019-01-08 |            2
> SAT 2019-01-05 |    2 | FRI 2019-01-11 |            4
> SAT 2019-01-05 |    3 | MON 2019-01-14 |            6
> SAT 2019-01-05 |    4 | TUE 2019-01-15 |            6
> SAT 2019-01-05 |    5 | WED 2019-01-16 |            6
> SAT 2019-01-05 |    6 | THU 2019-01-17 |            6
> SUN 2019-01-06 |    0 | TUE 2019-01-08 |            2
> SUN 2019-01-06 |    1 | FRI 2019-01-11 |            4
> SUN 2019-01-06 |    2 | MON 2019-01-14 |            6
> SUN 2019-01-06 |    3 | TUE 2019-01-15 |            6
> SUN 2019-01-06 |    4 | WED 2019-01-16 |            6
> SUN 2019-01-06 |    5 | THU 2019-01-17 |            6
> SUN 2019-01-06 |    6 | FRI 2019-01-18 |            6
> MON 2019-01-07 |    0 | MON 2019-01-07 |            0
> MON 2019-01-07 |    1 | TUE 2019-01-08 |            0
> MON 2019-01-07 |    2 | FRI 2019-01-11 |            2
> MON 2019-01-07 |    3 | MON 2019-01-14 |            4
> MON 2019-01-07 |    4 | TUE 2019-01-15 |            4
> MON 2019-01-07 |    5 | WED 2019-01-16 |            4
> MON 2019-01-07 |    6 | THU 2019-01-17 |            4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d93d81e8bcde8c59c01d7dcd65b0a430)*

Answer (score -1):

For the fifth first, you just have to add at then end of you request :

```
fetch first 5 rows only
```

For just one row you can use (at then end...) :

```
fetch first row only
```

You first select the 5th first rows (ordered by date descending), then you select the only first row ordering the previous result by date ascending.

Your SQL becomes :

```
select * from (
with s_date as (select TO_DATE('21-04-2020','DD-MM-YYYY') d from dual),
     e_date as (select TO_DATE('01-05-2020','DD-MM-YYYY') d from dual),
     no_of_days as (select abs(trunc(s_date.d -  e_date.d))+1 no from s_date,e_date),
    cal as (select d+rownum-1 dt
            from s_date
            connect by level <= (select no from no_of_days) )
select cal.dt  from cal where to_char(cal.dt, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
and cal.dt not in (select day from T_PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS)
order by cal.dt desc
fetch first 5 rows only
) x
order by x.dt
fetch first row only
;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check below query and let me know whether your issue is resolved or not .

```
with s_date as (select TO_DATE('21-04-2020','DD-MM-YYYY') d from dual),
     e_date as (select TO_DATE(DT_EXPR_PLDG,'DD-MM-YYYY') d from T_ANCRDT_FNNCL_C_FR where DT_EXPR_PLDG is not null ),
     no_of_days as (select abs(trunc(s_date.d -  e_date.d))+1 no from s_date,e_date),
    cal as (select d+rownum-1 dt
            from s_date
            connect by level <= (select no from no_of_days) )
select cal.dt  from cal where to_char(cal.dt, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
AND to_char (date '21-04-2020', 'D')=5 -- you can add weekday() function as well 
and cal.dt not in (select day from T_PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS) 
order by cal.dt desc;
```

Comment: SQL does not work. TO_CHAR('21-04-2020'D)=4 gives an ORA-00907 error...

Comment: You are working with SQL database or oracle, If SQL database then you can use DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '21-04-2020')

Comment: Tags say "oracle". Think it's an Oracle SQL request.

Comment: you can use Weekday () instead of this expressionTO_CHAR('21-04-2020'D)=4

Comment: I just don't understand why you solution resolve the question. And what is this "WeekDay" function ? Not an Oracle function, as far as I know.